# How to create equi-triangle-remeshed object?

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make many round holes on a smooth-shaped mesh (scanned for 3D printing) as evenly as possible, and currently I found a way to do that by:

- create a low-res remeshed version of original shape, whose grid is used as a guide;
- spawn many small cylinders by *Object Properties - Instancing*;
- apply instances, then boolean modifier.

However, the *Remesh* tool in *Object Data Properties* only creates quad meshes, and the result grid is not so even: it tend to spawn tighter edges along one direction and looser on the other direction, which make holes distribute uneven. So how could I create a low-res evenly-distributed triangle mesh from an original one?

[image: cylinders located by voxel-remeshed low-res instancing and some manual adjustments]

[image: voxel-remeshed low-res guide shape]

Comment: Could you add an image of an object as an example? I think I understand, but an [edit] would be helpful to understand what you are beginning with, working with etc.

Comment: @Timaroberts images added for explaining the situation